# Creating a floating Iframe in the center of the screen

Tags: html, dom, iframe, styling

I have an Iframe which I want to position in the center of the screen.
It should stay in the center when scrolling.
It should also be transparent.

How can I achieve all this?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give more details? How big iframe should be? Can you add sample html and CSS?

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this? If so can you post some of your html/css etc.

Comment: @Observer the Iframe should be half of the screen width and with 100px of height, it should be positioned 10% from top and centered

Comment: @Akrion I tried adding position: relative and left: 40% but to no avail

Comment: Please include sample code